# Log only when button is pushed (Re-rendering issue)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks

Consider the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';


const App = () => {
  let [count , setCount] = React.useState(0)
  let [approval , setApproval] = React.useState(false)
  let [text , setText] = React.useState('')


  
  const bogusCheck = (text) =>{
    let textArray = text.split(' ')
    console.log(textArray);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Enter a sentence below and click the button below:</p>
      <textarea cols="30" rows='10' value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value) } />
      <br />
      <button onClick={bogusCheck(text)} >Profanity Check</button>
    </div>

  );
}
export default App;
```

What I want to do is that when the user enters a whole sentence and pushed the button, the following occurs:

1. The whole sentence is passed down as a parameter to the bogusCheck() function.
2. The sentence is converted into array using the array.split(' ') function.
3. Lastly the whole array is console logged.

The problem is that each time I write a letter it gets logged in the console even if the button is not pressed. And if the array is used in more cases such as I will use it for a loop and conditional, I get the re-rendering error.

How do I solve this??

Much Obliged.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `onClick` handler is being evaluated in each render, that prop should receive a function and it's getting a value, just change that line like this:

```
<button onClick={() => bogusCheck(text)} >Profanity Check</button>
```